# Cannot parse nested json file

Tags: json, swift

Trying to parse nested json that contains a element named 'weather'. I run into errors with in the line: try decoder.decode(WeatherClass.Top.self, it errors out.
However if I remove the weather element from struct definition then it works.  Don't know how to figure out the struct construct and code for parsing nested json

JSON Listing:

```
{"lat":39.9295,"lon":-85.608,"timezone":"America/Chicago","timezone_offset":-18000,"current":{"dt":1690514755,"sunrise":1690457901,"sunset":1690507157,"temp":302.6,"feels_like":306.89,"pressure":1015,"humidity":70,"dew_point":296.55,"uvi":0,"clouds":0,"visibility":10000,"wind_speed":1.54,"wind_deg":0,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}]}}
```

Struct definition:

```
struct Top : Codable {
    let lat: Double
    let lon: Double
    let timezone: String?
    let timezone_offset: Double
    let current: CurrentJSON?
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case lat = "lat"
        case lon = "lon"
        case timezone = "timezone"
        case timezone_offset = "timezone_offset"
        case current = "current"
    }
}

struct CurrentJSON: Codable {
    let dt:Int //convert to date time
    let sunrise:Int
    let sunset:Int
    let temp:Double
    let feels_like:Double
    let pressure: Int
    let humidity: Int
    let dew_point: Double
    let uvi:Double
    let clouds: Int
    let visibility:Int
    let wind_speed: Double
    let wind_deg: Int
    let weather: WeatherJSON?
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case dt = "dt"
        case sunrise = "sunrise"
        case sunset = "sunset"
        case temp = "temp"
        case feels_like = "feels_like"
        case pressure = "pressure"
        case humidity = "humidity"
        case dew_point = "dew_point"
        case uvi = "uvi"
        case clouds = "clouds"
        case visibility = "visibility"
        case wind_speed = "wind_speed"
        case wind_deg = "wind_deg"
        case weather = "weather"
    }
}

 struct WeatherJSON: Codable {
    let id: String?
    let main: String?
    let description: String?
    let icon: String? 
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case main = "main"
        case description = "description"
        case icon = "icon"
    }
}
```

Code Listing:

```swift
func getWeatherCurrentDay(url: URL,
                                 latitudeStr: String,
                                 longitudeStr: String,
                          completion: @escaping (Bool, currentWeather) -> () ){

    
    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!) { [self] responseData, response, error in
        do {
            
            if let data = responseData {
               // let _ = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)
                self.jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
                print("JSON String:\(String(describing: self.jsonString))")
                
                if self.jsonString != nil {
                    try DispatchQueue.main.sync { [unowned self] in
                        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                        let jsonData = try decoder.decode(Top.self, from: data
                            // parse data here
                        }
                    }
                }
        } catch {
               print("error")
        }
                        
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace `print("error")` with `print(error)` so the actual error is printed. Then you'll the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weather field is an array of objects in the JSON response but in your CurrentJSON struct weather is defined as a single object. Additionally, the weather id field in the JSON response is being returned as an int but you are decoding it as a string

The correct models would look like:

```
struct WeatherJSON: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let main: String?
    let description: String?
    let icon: String?
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case main = "main"
        case description = "description"
        case icon = "icon"
    }
}
```

```
struct CurrentJSON: Codable {
    let dt: Int
    let sunrise: Int
    let sunset: Int
    let temp: Double
    let feels_like: Double
    let pressure: Int
    let humidity: Int
    let dew_point: Double
    let uvi: Double
    let clouds: Int
    let visibility: Int
    let wind_speed: Double
    let wind_deg: Int
    let weather: [WeatherJSON]?
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case dt = "dt"
        case sunrise = "sunrise"
        case sunset = "sunset"
        case temp = "temp"
        case feels_like = "feels_like"
        case pressure = "pressure"
        case humidity = "humidity"
        case dew_point = "dew_point"
        case uvi = "uvi"
        case clouds = "clouds"
        case visibility = "visibility"
        case wind_speed = "wind_speed"
        case wind_deg = "wind_deg"
        case weather = "weather"
    }
}
```

```
struct Top : Codable {
    let lat: Double
    let lon: Double
    let timezone: String?
    let timezone_offset: Double
    let current: CurrentJSON?
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case lat = "lat"
        case lon = "lon"
        case timezone = "timezone"
        case timezone_offset = "timezone_offset"
        case current = "current"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the "struct WeatherJSON", "id" is actually **Int**, not **String**.

That is why it is failing.

Comment: There is already an accepted answer that states the same. Why did  you answer the same, but partial?